# Is it possible to check if a hash was generated using SHA1 and is a valid hash?

Tags: c#, sha, hmacsha1

I ran into an issue where I want to validate a hash which was generated using SHA1. Is it possible to reverse engineer and figure out if the hash was generated using HMACSHA1 algo?

Comment: Do you have access to the data that was hashed?

Comment: Practically? If you don't have the original message used to generate the hash? No. It's a one-way hash.

Comment: What's your context here? Where are your hashes coming from and why do you think they might not be hashed correctly? What are you doing with the hashes on your side? Pretty much if somebody sends you a hash and says it's SHA1, you have to take their word for it. Presumably if they send you it again some time later, they will have hashed it the same way, so it won't really matter. There is the trivial check of making sure it's the right length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing in a hash code that can tell you what algorithm was used to create it. Any strong hash code algorithm is specifically designed to not contain any traceable meta data in the hash code. There is no specific markers that identifies the hash code as being a hash code, or what kind of algorithm was used.

Basically a hash algorithm tries to create a strong pseuo-random number using all the input as seed. The output is just as random as possible, there are no recognisable patterns that could be used to identify the input data or the algorithm.

If you have the input data that was used to create the hash code, you could recreate it and compare the results. However, if just a single bit in the input is different you get a completely different hash code, so the input has to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data that was hashed, then you can use a SHA1 hash on that data and compare the hash values to see if they are the same.  If they are equal then the SHA1 was used originally.

In short you can't go backwards by reverse engineering the hash function.